# drupal 8: having multiple value for a custom field

Tags: drupal

We need to create a custom field that has 3 parts: field label that static, field type that is drop down Taxonomy terms and field value that is input string. How we can create this kind of field?

Comment: Read this: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I read about creating custom field and modules. That is not the case now! The problem now is, how to use existed Taxonomies in my custom field?